# Why vim source _vimrc doesn't work while deleting some configurations but work for adding some?

Tags: vim

In my _vimrc i uncomment the line `" noremap  <a-j> :m+<CR>`, then execute `:w` `:so %` the map works well. Whereas, the map still works when i comment the line back and execute `:w` `:so %` like before. Have i done something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've sourced `_vimrc` with a mapping (that actuated the mapping), commented out the mapping and sourced again. The mapping is still actuated because there was no command that deleted it. If you want to remove a mapping unmap it:

```
unmap  <a-j>
```